# Sitecore and Azure Cosmos DB: number of requests abnormally high

Tags: xdb, azure, cosmos-db

I am using Azure Cosmos DB as my xDB, I am currently at test phase and have very few data and requests made by my app. I know this is not a fully supported platform, still I find it very useful and easy to use.

When my app is runing, I have an incredibly high number of requests registered by the db,

[image]

I am very surprised to see that, even when there is no visit on the cd website, during the night (which is not in production, so there was absolutely no one), there are 2k queries, updates and 6k other requests.

When I disable xDB, the number of requests goes to 0 and I still get other 
requests (in an affordable number though)

[image]

Is that normal behaviour ? Is there something I can fix to lower the number of requests ?

Comment: Is not recommended to use Azure Cosmos DB because is not tested by Sitecore.

Comment: While not supported yet; attempts and experimentation with running xDB on other backend platforms is definitely on-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes, I know this, still as it is really easy to use, I tried and wanted to see what was feasible with this. If there is no solution, I'll switch back to old mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at your aggregation services? These regularly hit the collection database and update the reporting SQL tables and the analytics index by aggregating the information in xDB. Try disabling your processing server (or processing configs if you do have a separate service running) and see if you still get all those requests.